# BigQuery - How to unnest multiple arrays, and distribute values from one column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with multiple arrays, and one column that acts like a key:

[image]

The question is how to unnest this structure so that each row also gets the rowkey value?

For example:

domain, event, ... referrer should also have the same rowkey?

Tried basically using unnest on the whole table.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  UNNEST(`table.bigtable_analytics.frontend`)
LIMIT
  1000
```

But getting an issue regarding table names:

Unrecognized name: `table.bigtable_analytics.frontend` at [4:10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly schema of your table, so below example (for BigQuery Standard SQL) just uses simplified schema to introduce the approach to get done what you asked: `each row also gets the rowkey value`

simplified dummy data is:

```
Row     rowkey  column.name column.value     
1       key1    domain      aaa.com  
                event       pageload     
                hash        12345    
2       key2    domain2     aaa2.com     
                event2      pageload2    
                hash2       123456789     

#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'key1' rowkey, [STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>('domain', 'aaa.com'), STRUCT('event', 'pageload'), STRUCT('hash', '12345')] column UNION ALL
  SELECT 'key2', [STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>('domain2', 'aaa2.com'), STRUCT('event2', 'pageload2'), STRUCT('hash2', '123456789')]
)
SELECT rowkey, x.*
FROM `project.dataset.table` t, t.column x
```

with result as

```
Row rowkey  name    value    
1   key1    domain  aaa.com  
2   key1    event   pageload     
3   key1    hash    12345    
4   key2    domain2 aaa2.com     
5   key2    event2  pageload2    
6   key2    hash2   123456789
```